# Mapped Sharepoint as Network Drives lost connection

Tags: networking, sharepoint, drive

In Citrix environment previously mapped Sharepoint as network drive is loosing the Connection every time users are connecting to virtual desktop. Is there a way to stop it from happening?
Right now users needs to do 5 additional steps to re-mapped it. It's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

i have a script which unmaps / remaps every night as part of a larger process.  you can change the delete to a specific drive

Unmap:

```
net use * /Delete /yes
```

Remap mappings to avoid the script prompting overwrite:

```
NET USE X: "\\projects.xxxx.com\Shared Documents\MyFolderName" /user:user124 xxxxxx /persistent:yes
```